# Unable to see Notification in Background in Lollipop

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am facing an issue in which I am not receiving notification when app is closed (kill) in android 5. Notification is coming on my other device which is android 7

I am doing it like:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("in On MessageReceived","true");
        remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        addNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"), remoteMessage.getData().get("Nick"));
    }
```

when I print log message then it doesn't get printed . So my onMessageReceived is not getting called.

When I done some reserch on net I found that I should use HandelIntent. I tried that too but same result

The Moment I send notification when app closed my Logcat show these messages

```
03-14 12:42:09.138 22931-22931/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
03-14 12:42:10.139 22931-22931/? W/Atfwd_Sendcmd: AtCmdFwd service not published, waiting... retryCnt : 3
03-14 12:42:13.463 2705-2705/? W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.thb.android.thunderBolt (has extras) }
03-14 12:42:14.454 1206-1238/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.thememanager for service com.android.thememanager/.service.ThemeTaskService: pid=25007 uid=9801 gids={49801, 9997, 2001, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023} abi=armeabi-v7a
03-14 12:42:14.524 1206-1238/? V/LocationPolicy: onProcessStateChanged
03-14 12:42:14.534 25007-25007/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/cloud-common.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
03-14 12:42:14.694 3388-3433/? I/XiaomiFirewall: firewall pkgName:com.android.thememanager, result:0
```

this is also in logcat

```
03-14 14:52:37.071 5222-5222/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
03-14 14:52:38.072 5222-5222/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
03-14 14:52:39.063 5222-5222/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
03-14 14:52:40.064 5222-5222/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
03-14 14:52:41.065 5222-5222/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
```

In backend(nodeJS) my code is

```
notification = function (arr, message, nick) {
    var message = {
        registration_ids: arr,
        data: {
            Nick: nick,
            body: message
        }
    };
    fcm.send(message, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)

        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response)
        }
    })
}
```

Can someone help me figuring out this problem . or what am I doing wrong. Its weird because its working on 1 device and not on another.

Comment: You need to send notification payload and data payload , if you send only data payload  some devices will not going to receive

Comment: mean need to send both from server?. I will give a try to it

Comment: seems like onMessageReceived is not getting called

Comment: Normally `onMessageReceived()` is called every time for data only payload, but here Xiaomi is preventing that. Try sending high priority message.

Comment: How to set priority in nodeJS FCM?

Comment: Try auto start on for your app in settings ?

Comment: yes auto start is the problem do you have any idea how to do it using code